# returning error code from open acc routine directive

Tags: gpu, openacc, pgi

I am porting a CPU code to GPU with OPENACC, 
the routine returns exit code

```
int myFunction()
{
// so stuff 
// it has a check for division by zero
int returnVal=SUCCESS;
if(fabs(a)<1e-14)
{
returnVal=1;
}
return(returnVal);
}
```

adding the

```
#pragma acc routine seq
int myFunction()
{
// so stuff 
// it has a check for division by zero
int returnVal=SUCCESS;
if(fabs(a)<1e-14)
{
returnVal=1;
}
return(returnVal);
}
```

will give the following error, 
call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 719: Launch failed (often invalid pointer dereference)

call to cuMemFreeHost returned error 719: Launch failed (often invalid pointer dereference)

---

Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.

If I eliminate the return by changing it to void, it works fine,
what is the correct way of doing this ? 
I do understand the race condition, given the fact that this is called inside a loop, should I privatize the return value and then perform a reduction on it?

Comment: Do you have a small reproducer you could post?  "returnVal" is declared locally to this function therefor is implicitly private, so I don't think that is the problem.  Though unfortunately, there's not enough information to determine what the issue is.

Comment: Hi Mat, this is a part of a bigger code unfortunately not easy to post here, I will see if I can regenerate it in a smaller section later today

Comment: That would be great.  If you can't pair it down, feel free to send it to PGI Customer Service (support@pgroup.com) and ask them to forward it to me.

Comment: Matt, I am acknowledging your helps in a conference paper, I hope you don't mind, you have been helping with a lot along the way so I felt I need to do that, thanks again

Comment: It's not necessary, but appreciated.